# get data from both collection and it is sub collection in firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

i have this database structure in Firestore:
[image] this what inside places [image]
how can i make a query in flutter to get all data inside Places sub-collection along with name from User collection, this code to get all places sub-collection data from every User collection :

```
Future<List<PlaceModel>> getPlaces() async {
    List<PlaceModel> placesList = [];
    // get all docs from user collection
    var users = await udb.get();
    for( var uid in users.docs) {
      var userData = await udb.doc(uid.id).get();
      var userPlaces = await udb.doc(uid.id).collection(placeTable).get();
      userPlaces.docs.forEach((place) {
            placesList.add(PlaceModel.fromMap(place.data()));
          });
    }
    return placesList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `where()` or `orderby()` methods to get data with some rules.

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(uid.id)
        .collection(placeTable)
        .where('fieldName', isEqualTo:name )
        .snapshots()
```

Answer (score 0):

A single query can only access a single collection, or a group of collection that have the same name. Firestore queries are shallow and don't read data from subcollections. If you need the data from the subcollection, you will have to execute an additional query to read it.

Comment: then what is the best way to do what i want? even if change the structure or any way? i just need to do that in any method, how can i make additional query? i don't have any idea about that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. To run an extra query, you just do the same as you now do for the parent collection - either once, or once for each document you got back.

Comment: Hey @OsamaMohammed. Did you get anywhere with this? If not, can you clarify what problem you run into when creating an extra query for the subcollection?

Comment: no i didn't do anything, because i don't know how create an extra query, i don't have any idea i there is no any tutorials about it

Comment: There is nothing different about the query for nested collections. Where are you stuck on it?